# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat: 8pm UTC on the 7th and 2am UTC on the 8th (now!)

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place**

- **Monday the 7th at 8pm UTC, 3pm EST** [(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=7&year=2011&hour=20&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)
- **Tuesday the 8th at 2am UTC, 9pm EST (on the 7th)** [(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=8&year=2011&hour=2&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

<sup>You gamers have polarized schedules!</sup>

**[click here to join](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/269/gaming-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match. <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. Since it isn't clear whether or not there will be a primary phase, I have to operate on the assumption that there won't be.  This means that I am looking at the 7th-9th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gaming.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the events [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/269/gaming-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: I can assure you, there will be a primary phase. Even if I have to make it happen.

Comment: It's a little confusing, but for EST the second meeting is still on Monday the 7th at 9PM.

Comment: @StrixVaria, that should be evident if you click the link to view in different timezones, but I did clarify it in the text, thanks.

Comment: Would I be ok if I was 10 minutes late? Sorry in advance.

Comment: badp had the date confused in the chat, so I figured I should clarify it here just to make sure no one who wants to attend misses out.

Answer (score 2):

I can help by combining these two town halls into a *single* "digest" posted as one large Meta question. I'll help make all questions from the first town hall are asked in the second town hall, and will help gather responses to all questions asked in the *second* town hall from all the attendees of the *first* town hall.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests)

I will update this answer with a link to the meta question when it is posted.

### Update:

[The Town Hall Chat Digest is now available](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)

Comment: Sounds promising!

Comment: Don't feel bad about "taking so long". Most of the Town Hall Chats don't happen until the actual election phase, so in a way this is actually going to be earlier than when most users get the digest.

Comment: Thanks @Grace! That makes me feel better. I'm almost done with the first towh hall, post coming soon!

Answer (score 1):

As I told Rebecca already, I'm likely not going to be present for the first town hall chat.  I have cable tech support scheduled to be here right when it starts.